# Opening file using mPdfViewer.fromFile(file) shows an empty pdf

Tags: java, android, pdf

I'm having a problem with opening file using PDFViewer library.

Inside DocumentCreator class:
1. First I create the document using iText library and it works perfectly fine and it writes document to the given directory. 
2. Then I create an object of a File to display it using PDFViewer.

```
try {
        mDocument = new Document(); // new Document created
        String path = "/" + FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid() + "-" + recipe.getTitle() + ".pdf";
        String fullPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/recipes" + path;
        mPdfWriter = PdfWriter.getInstance(mDocument, new FileOutputStream(fullPath));
        doTheWriting(recipe, activity);
        Log.d("OK", "done");

        mMyRecipeFile = new File(fullPath);

    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch (DocumentException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Inside same class (DocumentCreator) I created getter method for mMyRecipeFile.

```
public File getRecipeFile() {
    return mMyRecipeFile;
}
```

After that in the DocumentTestFragment,
I created PDFView, called mPdfView, and I try to open this file.

```
mPdfView.fromFile(mDocCreator.getRecipeFile());
```

The problem is it is displaying an empty document, which is weird, because I opened Android Device Monitor, opened given file and it's not empty.

Comment: `Log.d("OK", "done");` ?? Are you shure? You are not even checking the return value of doTheWriting().

Comment: `(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/recipes" + path)` You construct that path yet another time: `String fullPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/recipes" + path;`. Not good programming. Do it once. And use more times.

Comment: Yep, thanks for that. Agree, it's not the best programming. It is just a test, so I can see where the problem is. doTheWriting() works perfectly fine, the file is created and it's written. The problem is that the pdf file exists in given directory, but when I create an object of File it shows me empty pdf.

Comment: Will external apps show your pdf file ok?

Comment: Can you display other pdf files with pdf viewer?

Comment: 1. I'm testing it on virtual device
2.Yes, pdfViewer displays pdfs from assets, tried it on some random pdf file. 
3. I opened the file on my mac and its written

Comment: From assets. Ok. But also other pdf's from file?

Comment: Please use a real device.

Comment: Ok I'll work on it more and let you know if I figured it out. It's not opening different pdf file, when I use pdfView.fromFile(file).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found out what caused a problem. The thing is that I wrote:

```
PdfView.fromFile(file)
```

While proper form is

```
PdfView.fromFile(file).load();
```

It works just fine now.